# Image location data is corrupt when extracted using PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, exif

I have 2 programs to get the Exif data (specifically geolocation data) from pictures:

Number 1 (removed opening the file, etc to make it more concise):

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS

exif = {}

for tag, value in image._getexif().items():
    if tag in TAGS:
        exif[TAGS[tag]] = value

print("GPS Info: ", exif["GPSInfo"])
```

The output is:

```
GPS Info:  {5: 2.8}
```

Number 2 (removed opening the file, etc to make it more concise):

```
from PIL import Image, ExifTags

img_exif = img.getexif()

if img_exif:
    print(dict(img_exif))
    # { .. 271: 'FUJIFILM', 305: 'Adobe Photoshop Lightroom 6.14 (Macintosh)', }

    img_exif_dict = dict(img_exif)
    for key, val in img_exif_dict.items():
        if key in ExifTags.TAGS:
            print(ExifTags.TAGS[key] + " - " + str(val))
else:
    print("Sorry, image has no exif data.")
```

The output for `print(dict(img_exif))` is:

```
{34853: 684, 296: 2, 34665: 174, 271: 'QUALCOMM', 272: '4052R',
 306: '2020:07:02 07:18:35', 531: 1, 282: 72.0, 283: 72.0}
```

The output for `print(ExifTags.TAGS[key] + " - " + str(val))` is:

```
GPSInfo - 684
```

How do I get the image location data? If this is the correct data, how do I get it into a usable format (that I could put into google maps, etc).

Comment: I'm not sure if something is wrong with pillow's exif features or if I'm using it wrong, but the data it shows for my images is quite incomplete. Maybe just use a different exif library.

Comment: I couldn't find the latest version (2.32 dated 2010-04-26 according to Wikipedia) of the Exif specification online, but you can get a PDF of version 2.2 from [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20131019050323/http://www.exif.org/specifications.html). It shows what all the GPS tags are in section **4.6.6 GPS Attribute Information** starting on page 52.

Comment: @wups This is the only one I've found, is there a specific one you recommend?

Comment: I don't know it well enough to recommend, but https://pypi.org/project/exif/ looks good so far.

Comment: @Wups Thanks!!!

Comment: Did you solve this question?

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex no...

Comment: Is the info available in Lightroom?

Answer (score 0):

It is a little old, but I have the same problem, I solved using the binary output based in this [example](https://hhsprings.bitbucket.io/docs/programming/examples/python/PIL/ExifTags.html)

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS, GPSTAGS

def get_decimal_coordinates(info):
  try:
    #print(info)
    for key in ['Latitude', 'Longitude']:
        print('GPS'+key,'GPS'+key+'Ref')
        if 'GPS'+key in info.keys() and 'GPS'+key+'Ref' in info.keys():
            
            e = info['GPS'+key]
            print(e)
            ref = info['GPS'+key+'Ref']
            info[key] = ( e[0] + e[1] / 60 + e[2]/ 3600) * (-1 if ref in ['S','W'] else 1)
            print(info[key])
    if 'Latitude' in info and 'Longitude' in info:
        return [ float(info['Longitude']),float(info['Latitude'])]
    else:
        return [0.0, 0.0]
  except:       
    #print('e')
    return [0.0, 0.0]



def get_exif(image_file_path):
    _TAGS_r = dict(((v, k) for k, v in TAGS.items()))
    _GPSTAGS_r = dict(((v, k) for k, v in GPSTAGS.items()))
    exif_table = {}
    image = Image.open(image_file_path)
    exifd = image._getexif()
    keys = list(exifd.keys())
    keys = [k for k in keys if k in TAGS]
    gpsinfo = exifd[_TAGS_r["GPSInfo"]]
    gps_info = {}
    for k in gpsinfo.keys():
        gps_info[GPSTAGS[k]]= gpsinfo[k]# [str((GPSTAGS[k], gpsinfo[k])) for k in gpsinfo.keys()]
    info = image.getexif()
    for tag, value in info.items():
        decoded = TAGS.get(tag, tag)
        exif_table[decoded] = value
    #print(exif_table)
    lat,lon=get_decimal_coordinates(gps_info)
    return (lat,lon)
```